# Showing reports from SSRS on asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, reportviewer2008

I have trouble with my reports of Reporting Services on an asp.net page. When I call the report (which is a table with a graphic in a specific column of the table) from my asp.net app it does not show me the graphic on the table cell, but when I see the same report at ReportServer from Reporting Services it shows me the graphic inside the specific column of the table. Have you had a problem like that? 
*The report is displayed on a reportviewer from visual-studio 2008.

Comment: can you show relevant code?

Comment: Well I just made my report with a Reporting Services Project from Microsoft BI Studio. Then I created my app on asp.net and used a Report Viewer to link de report server url...just that. I do not have a specific code for it.

Comment: By graphic, do you mean chart or image? If image, embedded or external? I've had issues with external images and permission issues. :(

Comment: have you tried different browsers?  I have had LOTS of issue with IE 11

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the report viewing control on the web page, you could call the SSRS service from your web page, and render the report results in MHTML, convert the MHTML into html and display this on your web page.